# Book: Learning ROS for Robotic Programming, 2nd Edn; Chapter 6 - pcl_create not working

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to go through the book recommended for the ROS beginners "Learning ROS for Robotics Programming" Second Edition. Right now, I am reading chapter 6 about point cloud library. I have followed all the steps given in there from page 236-240. I am constantly seeing this error

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named pcl_create below /home/khan/catkin_ws/src/chapter6_tutorials
```

even though the command  `catkin_make` is being compiled in my root directory and no error occurs. To resolve this problem I have already gone through all the solutions provided online such as [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/64763/change-path-of-rosrun-couldnt-find-executables/), [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/60286/rosrun-not-finding-executable/) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/199276/rosrun-couldnt-find-executable-named/). Tried everything such as

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
source devel/setup.bash

echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/khan/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks

$ rospack profile

Full tree crawl took 0.029871 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.028046   /opt/ros/jade/share
0.001151   /home/khan/catkin_ws/src
0.000042 * /opt/ros/jade/share/doc
0.000010 * /opt/ros/jade/share/realsense
0.000008 * /opt/ros/jade/share/doc/liborocos-kdl

roscd chapater6_tutorials
rosrun chapter6_tutorials pcl_create
```

and that's what I get

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named pcl_create below /home/khan/catkin_ws/src/chapter6_tutorials
```

I have also tried running it from the root directory such

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
rosrun chapter6_tutorials pcl_create
```

still got the same answer.

My "chapter6_tutorials" package address is home/catkin_ws/src/chatper6_tutorials. In my" chapter6_tutorials", I have two files CMakeLists.txt and package.xml and only one folder naming "src" in which I have two files "pcl_sample" and "pcl_create" both of these files are created as per instructions given in the book. In my CMakesLists.txt I have already added following instructions

```
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)

## Add include directories
include_directories(include
      ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Add link directories
link_directories(
  ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

add_executable(pcl_sample src/pcl_sample.cpp)
add_executable(pcl_create src/pcl_create.cpp)

target_link_libraries(pcl_sample ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(pcl_create ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

It is also worth mentioning that I am using ubuntu15.04 with jade version of ROS.

I have already learnt how to create package from the tutorial ([this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage)) and I have also gone through how to make nodes following book and tutorials ([a](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) and [b](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingPublisherSubscriber)).
Please, help if you can. I have spent a lot of time in it and stuck. Please, help, I shall bring cookies for you. :D :D :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224799/book:-learning-ros-for-robotic-programming,-2nd-edn;-chapter-6---pcl_create-not-working/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-22**:
Please edit your question to include the full layout of your workspace (or at least, something that shows where `chapter6_tutorials` is located, and what it's contents is). You could use something like `tree` for that. Also: please add the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt`.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-01-22**:
Thanks gvdhoorn for your attention. I have edited my question for the very important information I missed. I am so grateful to you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is that your whole CMakeLists.txt? I wouldn't expect that to properly build your executables because of missing catkin dependencies at the top. Further, it appears you are missing a call to the `catkin_package()` macro ([documentation here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html?highlight=catkin_package#catkin-package)). One of the things this macro does is tell catkin where to put the compiled executables. If they aren't in the right place, then `rospack` (and correspondingly `rosrun`) won't be able to find them.

I'm guessing if you run the command

```
 find ~/catkin_ws -name "pcl_create" -executable
```

it will tell you the compiled binary is located in `~/catkin_ws/build/`, but if you add a call to `catkin_package()` before your `add_executable` lines then you will find the executable in `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/` (which is where it should be).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-01-25**:
I was so in loosing hope that nobody helps here; but here I got your message and it worked. Hurrah!!!  Thank you so much Jarvisschutlz. I shall buy cookies for you and give away to some poor person by your name. :) :) :). You helped me so much and I cannot pay you back anyways. This is so much to me